# Is the value of primitive types in std::map initialized?

Tags: c++, primitive-types, stdmap

Consider the following code:

```
map<int,int> m;
for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) m[i]++;
for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) printf("%d",m[i]);
```

I thought the the values printed out would be undefined because primitive types doesn't have default constructor, but here I got 10000 1s every time I tested.

Why is it initialized?

Comment: 0 is a legal value for undefined variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When invoking `operator[]` and the key is missing, the value is initialized using the expression `mapped_type()` which is the default constructor for class types, and zero initialization for integral types.

Comment: Hmm actually, are you sure this is the answer? On [map::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/) it says: "
A call to this function is equivalent to:
(*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second" which suggests the value-initialization of pair doesn't matter

Comment: Are you sure with cplusplus.com?

Comment: Chris has a point. The default constructor of `pair` obviously is not used - the `first` member of the pair is the integer index `i` which runs from 0 to 10000 here. If the default ctor would have been used, the `first` member would have been zero, and as a map can't contain duplicate keys there would have only a single map entry. As we know that 10000 ones were printed, we know the default pair ctor was not used.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: you're right I wasn't thinking about which version of the constructor would be called, but the call to `mapped_type()` is going to do the same thing, no? I think in order to have an uninitialized value you would have to go out of your way in your map implementation to do something like an uninitialized value on the stack and then explicitly pass it into make_pair. So I guess the correct answer is that map is just always guaranteed to default construct the value type when the key is missing, and that default constructors for primitive types always zero initialize?

Comment: Yeah, sounds right to me. I guess I would just say "when the key is missing, the value is initialized using the expression `mapped_type()` which is default ctor for class types, and zero initialization for integral types."

Answer (score 5):

[std::map::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) inserts new value if it's not exist. If an insertion is performed, mapped value is initialized by default-constructor for class-types or [zero-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

See https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_map.h

```
  _Tp& operator[](const key_type& __k) {
    iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
    // __i->first is greater than or equivalent to __k.
    if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
      __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, _Tp()));
    return (*__i).second;
  }
```

In your example, _Tp is `int`, and `int()` is 0

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int x = int();
  cout << x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In addition:

thanks to @MSalters who tells about code above is SGI instead of std::map, But I think it is some like...

Comment: That's actually the STL `map` class, not `std::map`. The latter was inspired by the former, but there are minor differences. And this question is about a minute detail. But yes, as it happens there are no differences right here.

Comment: you are right, there are many stl versions, SGI, STLPort, microsoft version, etc.

Comment: If Microsoft ever had a STL-derived library, it was 2 decades ago. (VC4 perhaps, don't recall the details). They definitely switched to Dinkumware's implementation by VC6, a C++98 Standard Library implementation.

Comment: How time flies! when I last used VC6 I was in my Colloege, 9 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

In the C++14 standard, section `[map.access]` the text is:

> `T& operator[](const key_type& x);`
>
> 1. Effects: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.

So, as also stated by Joseph Garvin's answer, the result of the expression `mapped_type()` is what is inserted.  This sort of initialization is called [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

The meaning of value-initialization is not quite as simple as offered in the other answers, for class types. It depends on what sort of constructors the class type has, and whether the class is an aggregate, as explained by the cppreference link.

For `int` as in this question, value-initialization means the `int` is set to `0`.