# Safe to rely on a initialised value in an unordered_map (hashmap)

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map, value-initialization

Let's say I wanted to construct an `std::unordered_map<char, int>` to map the frequency of characters in a string. I would do something like

```
char* myString;
std::unordered_map<char, int> hashmap;
for(char* pch = myString; *pch !=0 ; pch++)
{
     hashmap[*pch]++;
}
```

This, to me, feels dangerous as how do I know `hashmap[*pch]++` will construct an integer in the value of the hashmap entry that starts at 0? Where do I find this guarantee (if it exists)?

Comment: You can find the guarantee by reading documentation. It's perfectly safe because `unordered_map::operator[]` will first insert a value initialized `int`, i.e. `0`, if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reference for the language and standard library [covers this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) at least if you follow the link to value initialization as Praetorian mentioned.  See also [Is the value of primitive types in std::map initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549057/8586227) (for which the answer is the same).